# Converting from hex str to int fails for one dataframe column while it works for another with "TypeError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, hex

I'm reading from a csv file where two of the columns are "start" and "end". Both columns contain large hex values. Since both columns are in string format, I convert them to int so that I can perform a subtraction between `start[i+1]` and `end[i]`.

```
data['start_int'] = data['start'].apply(int, base=16)
data['end_int']   = data['end'].apply(int, base=16)
```

I see following error ***only*** for column "start" while it works just fine for column "end".

> TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

`isinstance(start[0], str)` is ***True***

`isinstance(end[0], str)` is ***True***

Initial few rows of start and end columns.

```
start                                             end 
0                                                 030C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C2F 
030C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30C30  61900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
61900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000   92500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I don't understand why python complains only for one column while it works for another.

Comment: Without the actual csv file, this is difficult to solve?, because the traceback message is self explanatory, there is a data type that is non-string, which `int` cannot convert

Comment: @ironFist, I have uploaded a sample file here - https://filebin.net/4a0uw7mz7wouqn8h - Why does it work for 2nd column and fails for 1st? Is it because the first column first index is "0" ?

Comment: How did you know it only works for second column?

Comment: You issue is non-reproducible, I was able to convert all string into their hex value